# Push firmware files in ath10k to Debian firmware-atheros

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, firmware

I would like to quote wireless.wiki.kernel.org:

> The ath10k firmware images are available from linux-firmware.git which all common Linux distributions should install by default. Latest firmware images can be downloaded from ath10k-firmware.git from which they get eventually pushed to linux-firmware.git.

Last time I checked git.kernel.org, I found the [commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/?id=8afadbe553017bec1e442b5a9fba859b54fd33fb) happened last May 3, 2016 pushing the new firmware files from a Qualcomm developer to the kernel.

My questions are:

1. How and when will the firmware files arrive to Debian? [firmware-atheros page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-atheros) in sid right now doesn't contain the QCA9377 firmware files.
2. Is there any change the files will be received in stable (jessie)?

If you want the background of my problem, you can check my thread.

Answer (score 2):

> How and when will the firmware files arrive to Debian?

They'll arrive in the same way as usual, *via* a [`firmware-nonfree`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/firmware-nonfree) update; since `linux-firmware` now includes the Atheros update, the new files should be included. As to when, only the maintainer knows that; you should really file a bug so that he's aware that an update could be useful:

```
reportbug firmware-atheros
```

> Is there any change the files will be received in stable (jessie)?

Previous updates have been backported (*e.g.* [last February](https://tracker.debian.org/news/750404)), so I'd imagine the next updates will be too.

Comment: Thanks, will have to contact debian kernel maintainers then.